# Postgresql create stored database link

Tags: sql, postgresql, dblink

I know that in Oracle it's possible to create stored dblink and after that use it in query. For example:

Script for creation dblink:

```
CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK my_link CONNECT TO my_schema IDENTIFIED BY shema_password USING 'remote';
```

And after that we can use it in our queries:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table@my_link;
```

I didn't find same solution for Postgres. I undestood that we can create named dblink connection:

For this we must use `dblink_connect` with name param. But created named dblink will destroy after session close.

Or we can create dblink connection for every queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM dblink('host= port= dbname= user= password=',
            'select table_schema, table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema = ''data''') AS t1 (table_schema TEXT, table_name TEXT);
```

Is it possible create stored dblink in Postgres and use it in different queries? Or I should create some function that return dblink connection params which encapsulate them?

**I try use foreign table and do next steps:**

**Create postgres_fdw extension:**

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgres_fdw;
```

**Create Server:**

```
CREATE SERVER my_server FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw OPTIONS (host '-', port '-', dbname '-');
```

**And create mapping for user 'sys' where set remote user and password:**

```
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR sys SERVER light_house OPTIONS ( USER 'remote_user', PASSWORD 'remove_password');

GRANT USAGE ON FOREIGN SERVER my_server TO sys;
```

**Create foreign table in schema:**

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE system.my_local_table (
  colums ..
) SERVER my_server OPTIONS (schema_name 'remote_user', table_name 'remote_table'
);

GRANT SELECT ON TABLE system.home_measurement TO argus_sys;
```

**after that I catch next exception:**

```
[2F003] ERROR: password is required 
Description: Non-superuser cannot connect if the server does not request a password. 
Help: Target server's authentication method must be changed.
```

Comment: "*Non-superuser cannot connect if the server does not request a password*" - you honestly run a production server that does not require a password to connect?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry, but I don't undestand. I declare passord to remote user in user mapping (I updated question and added scripts) and I thing that it's enough or I wrong?

Comment: The error message seems to indicate that your server does not _require_ a password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a [*foreign table*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-foreign-data.html).

To get rid of the error message, change the `pg_hba.conf` file on the remote database server to use `md5` authentication (don't forget to reload with `pg_ctl reload`).

Comment: I try create foreign table but I can't use it with non superuser. I updated my question, please look it.

Comment: When you say: "foreign server" you mean "remote db instance", right? There I must add configuration for my "local db instance" for example: `host    remote_db_name           remote_user_name         local_ip      md5`

Comment: Right, that's what I mean.